# Pass unicode binary data as a parameter for XLRD's open_workbook method

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to pass `unicode` binary data as a parameter (`file_contents`) for XLRD's `open_workbook`. The data file type is `.xls`.

Documentation from an [article](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html).

```
open_workbook(filename=None, logfile=sys.stdout, verbosity=0, pickleable=True, use_mmap=USE_MMAP, file_contents=None, encoding_override=None, formatting_info=False, ) 

file_contents
... as a string or an mmap.mmap object or some other behave-alike object. If file_contents is supplied, filename will not be used, except (possibly) in messages.
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/book.py).

I've tried doing this:

```
input = StringIO.StringIO()
input.write(vals['data'])

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=input.getvalue())
```

But there is an error:

```
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '0M8R4KGx'
```

What do I do?

Comment: Where did you get `vals['data']`? Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Robᵩ It's hard to do that, cause my program depends on `Odoo` framework. But when I use `type()` it says `unicode`. The file itself is actually of `.xls` format, odoo basically just accepts the upload as binary and I can access it through `vals['data']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I note that your data begins with the string `0M8R4KGx`. I further note that `base64.decodestring('0M8R4KGx')` yields `\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1`, which is the first several bytes of an XLS file.

The string in `vals['data']` is a base64-encoded string. You must first decode it before writing it to a file, like so:

```
input.write(base64.decodestring(vals['data']))
```

or

```
input.write(vals['data'].decode('base64'))
```

Reference:

- https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/upload-files-to-openerp-through-custom-module-16828